# Are there specific gems, or ways that gems specifically, interact with radiation?

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, radiation

In my world, I'm looking into the prospect of having gems/gemstones interact (possibly contain) radiation. I am mostly considering Gamma or Beta radiation, but it's not a strict requirement. 
My actual inquiry is this: **Are there any known gems, or properties of gems, that have a significant impact on radiation?** 
I would prefer to use multiple types of gems in my world ( with them being of varying usefulness ), but I could also make a single gem plentiful enough to be used widely, if something like diamond had unique properties.
Also bear in mind that I'm creating a fantasy world, so a little bending of the rules can be applied.

Comment: This sounds like question about geology and not building your world.

Comment: What is the difficulty in looking up [gem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemstone) on Wikipedia, and then following up with the specific gems such as diamond, ruby, sapphire, and emerald (collectively called "precious stones")? The answer is of course that gems, especially when properly cut, interact with visible light, which is a form electromagnetic radiation, in such a way as to appear beautiful to human eyes and minds. Other than that, gems are not that much different from any other old stone.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_battery  but in general, it is not clear which type of interaction you are asking for.

Comment: I want to use geology in my world. The question pertains to world-building in that I trying to use somewhat realistic properties of gems, however I do **not** need to obey the known laws of physics or properties of all gems. I'm searching for interactions I can build off, and seeing if there are any 'short leaps' people can make to use gems as an energy ( as radiation ) source in my world. And as stated in my question, I am looking for interactions mostly based outside electromagnetic radiation. I accept that the question is a little broad, but  it's world *building*

Comment: Nominating for re-opening because this is a reality check for a component of a world the author is building. This is about as on-topic as it gets around here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [thermoluminescent dosimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoluminescent_dosimeter), is a crystal that absorbs energy from radiation, changing its crystalline structure as the energy is absorbed. When the crystal is heated, the energy trapped in crystal changes is released as optical light. This light can then be measured to determine how much radiation the crystalline structure received over time.

I suppose if you like to pseudo-science things, you could use such crystals as a bridge to a technology that uses them to store energy. The released light energy could be used for things like lasers. Honestly, that sounds kinda like how the radium guns worked in [*A Princess of Mars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Princess_of_Mars).

Comment: This is why i love the internet. This fits what i'm looking for 100%, I'll bend the rules a bit in my universe to be sure, but this lets me have an actual reason to combine gems and magic.

Answer (score 4):

Gem-to-radiation interactions, or the reverse?
**Some gemstones are processed with artificial radiation to alter their properties (usually color.)  Topaz is the most common result, turning from yellow(ish) to blue.  Diamonds often turn green.**

See particularly the data table of minerals in:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemstone_irradiation

Comment: I was looking a little more at other properties, but color could be useful as well, interesting!